a piano piece transcribed for the guitar

a piano piece transcribed for the guitar

What's the meaning of 'a piano piece'?

an original piano piece (change doesn't exist)
a piano piece that has been adapted for the guitar (change does exist but still is in the form of a piano piece; a music score for a piano)
no piano piece; a piano piece was changed for the guitar performance and no longer used or useful for piano performance; it is now a music score for a guitar.

ps. I'm a layperson on music.

Speaking as someone with a classical guitar background, I would understand this phrase...

a piano piece transcribed for the guitar

...as pointing in both directions. A piano piece points backwards to existing music with connections to the piano. Transcribed for the guitar points forwards to the expression of that music with such changes as are necessary to make it compatible with the new instrument.
To take a simple example, consider Minuet in G major by Bach. The original was written for the keyboard (originally the harpsichord but since performed by generations of piano students). I have piano sheet music but I also have sheet music transcriptions for classical guitar. If we laid out the two versions side by side we would see that:

the substance of the music is identical (same melody, chords, harmonies, tempo etc).
various performance elements specific to guitar have been changed. For example the fingering is different, because it is a stringed instrument. Also the range of possible notes on a guitar is smaller than for piano. This means that by convention all classical guitar notes are all written on a single staff. (A staff is a set of five horizontal lines for writing music.) By contrast, the piano arrangement has two staffs, one for the left hand and one for the right hand.

Note that the amount of alteration in the transcription will vary depending on the instrument. In this example both the piano and guitar transcriptions are in the key of G major. But for some instruments with a different range of notes, the transcription might include changing the key.

What is a broken window?  Is it a window, even after it has been broken?  Let's not get into a philosophical discussion here, it doesn't help. You know what a "window" is, and you know what a "broken window" means. Breaking a window changes it.
Similarly "a piano piece" is a piece of music written for the piano.  "A piano piece transcribed for the guitar" is the result of taking that piece of music and changing it to a piece of music for the guitar.
Let the philosophers worry about ontology, it's not necessary to understand a simple expression like this.
The difference between this and the "broken window" example is that transcribing a piece of music does not destroy it.  After you have transcribed a piano piece, you get two scores.  The original piano score and the new guitar score.

I can see two possible meanings of transcribe:

We hear a piece of music and write down a score. That music might be a live performance or a recording.
We already have a score, presumably playable on one or more instruments and we produce a new version playable on a different instrument.

The act of transcribing cannot destroy the original piece. If we were transcribing a live performance then we might only get one chance to transcribe - (some people have very good musical memory and hear a piece once and then be able to reproduce it) - however it's not the act of transcription that would affect whether a live perfomance is lost.
When we transcribe a piano piece we are taking music that could have 10 different notes played at the same time to an instrument capable of playing at most 6 notes at the same time. Further the range of notes on a guitar is much smaller than that of a piano. So the resulting guitar piece may have fewer notes, and different notes from the original - typically we not only transcribe, we produce an arrangement. Hence, generally speaking, given just the guitar transcription we cannot guarantee to reconstruct the original piano piece - so information may be lost in making the transcription.

A "piece" in this context is a musical composition aka a  work.  It refers to the creation of the composer abstractly, just as, say, "novel" refers to the creation of the writer abstractly, that is, independent of any physical edition.
The prefix trans in the verb transcribe means "across".  We also see it in the verb translate.  These verbs do not entail any undoing of the original, although the result might be different from the original in a number of respects, though both transcription and translation usually seek to remain faithful to the original.
